# Starsky & Hutch - Why player's car right-side wheels are weird?

Tags: starsky-and-hutch

I remember a game that,I was playing when I was a child, it was called Starsky & Hutch, based on a series with same name.

I installed the game on my PC again, just to remember my old days. I remembered a question when I was a child and I still have this question: "Why most of player's car right-side wheels are weird? They're different from left-side wheels, but as in demos and intro movie, it shouldn't be like that. Is there anything special with that?"

I know this game is too old.